# Bucle para varios procedimientos

Tags: r

Partimos de estos datos:

```
structure(list(año = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022), municipio = c("municipio1", 
"municipio2", "municipio3", "municipio4", "municipio5", "municipio1", 
"municipio2", "municipio3", "municipio4", "municipio5", "municipio1", 
"municipio2", "municipio3", "municipio4", "municipio5"), ingresos = c(75, 
80, 85, 90, 95, NA, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130, 135, 140, 145
), gastos = c(50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 
550, NA, 650, 700, 750), poblacion = c(1000, 1200, 1300, NA, 
1001, 1500, 1301, 1351, 1002, 2000, 1302, 1352, 1500, 1203, 1800
)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)) -> datos



    año municipio  ingresos gastos poblacion
 1  2020 municipio1       75     50      1000
 2  2020 municipio2       80    100      1200
 3  2020 municipio3       85    150      1300
 4  2020 municipio4       90    200        NA
 5  2020 municipio5       95    250      1001
 6  2021 municipio1       NA    300      1500
 7  2021 municipio2      105    350      1301
 8  2021 municipio3      110    400      1351
 9  2021 municipio4      115    450      1002
10  2021 municipio5      120    500      2000
11  2022 municipio1      125    550      1302
12  2022 municipio2      130     NA      1352
13  2022 municipio3      135    650      1500
14  2022 municipio4      140    700      1203
15  2022 municipio5      145    750      1800
```

Quiero quitar los NA, para ello los voy a sustituir por la media de su municipio.

Calculo el ingreso medio:

```
datos %>% 
  group_by(municipio) %>% 
  mutate(ingresos_media = mean(ingresos, na.rm = T)) -> datos
```

Unifico los ingresos con los ingresos medios, para que el NA me lo cambie por la media, y el resto de los ingresos me los deje tal cual están:

```
datos <- sqldf("select *, coalesce(ingresos, ingresos_media ) ingresos2 from 'datos'")
```

Borro las dos columnas de ingresos:

```
borrar <- c("ingresos","ingresos_media")
datos <- datos [,!(names(datos) %in% borrar)]
```

Y le cambio el nombre a la columna creada:

```
datos <- rename(datos, c("ingresos" = "ingresos2"))
```

quedando:

```
     año  municipio gastos poblacion ingresos
1  2020 municipio1     50      1000       75
2  2020 municipio2    100      1200       80
3  2020 municipio3    150      1300       85
4  2020 municipio4    200        NA       90
5  2020 municipio5    250      1001       95
6  2021 municipio1    300      1500      100
7  2021 municipio2    350      1301      105
8  2021 municipio3    400      1351      110
9  2021 municipio4    450      1002      115
10 2021 municipio5    500      2000      120
11 2022 municipio1    550      1302      125
12 2022 municipio2     NA      1352      130
13 2022 municipio3    650      1500      135
14 2022 municipio4    700      1203      140
15 2022 municipio5    750      1800      145
```

Ahora lo quiero hacer en bucle para todas las columnas y nada más empezar ya me pierdo.

```
lista <- names(datos)[-c(1,2)]

for (i in lista){
media <- paste0(i,"_media")

datos %>% 
  group_by(municipio) %>% 
  mutate(media = mean(i, na.rm = T)) -> datos
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Usar mutate_at

El `tidyverse` probé la función [mutate_at](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html) que pueden lograr el objetivó que buscas. La idea detrás de esta función es básicamente aplicar una transformación a varias columnas a la vez. En particular `mutate_at` te permite seleccionar las variables que deseas transformar, pero tiene como hermanas a las funciones `mutate_all` y `mutate_if`, la primera para transformar todas las variables y la segunda para transformar aquellas que cumplan una condición definida.

Aquí el código:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

#Definir una funcion para remplazar NA

rem_na<-function(x, na.rm = T){
    ifelse(is.na(x),mean(x, na.rm = na.rm),x)
}

#Usando mutate_at para selecionar las variables a modificar
datos %>% 
  group_by(municipio) %>% 
  mutate_at(c("ingresos", "gastos","poblacion"), rem_na)
```

Y la salida:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 5
# Groups:   municipio [5]
     año municipio  ingresos gastos poblacion
   <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
 1  2020 municipio1       75     50     1000 
 2  2020 municipio2       80    100     1200 
 3  2020 municipio3       85    150     1300 
 4  2020 municipio4       90    200     1102.
 5  2020 municipio5       95    250     1001 
 6  2021 municipio1      100    300     1500 
 7  2021 municipio2      105    350     1301 
 8  2021 municipio3      110    400     1351 
 9  2021 municipio4      115    450     1002 
10  2021 municipio5      120    500     2000 
11  2022 municipio1      125    550     1302 
12  2022 municipio2      130    225     1352 
13  2022 municipio3      135    650     1500 
14  2022 municipio4      140    700     1203 
15  2022 municipio5      145    750     1800
```

Espero que no sea necesario usar ciclos para que la solución valga.